# Property-Editor for buttons messes up onClick value (inserts classname in brackets)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

Just upgraded to Android Studio 2.2 and used the Property-Editor for a button in the Design-View of a layout.xml. From there I can choose methods from my Activity, but after I select a method, a wrong value will be inserted to the onClick-Attribute:

For example: If I select the "doStuff" method it becomes

```
"android:onClick="get (MainActivity)"
```

Of course this doesn't work and on runtime the following error will be thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method doStuff (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'buttonDoStuff'
```

So am I doing something wrong when using the Property-Editor or is this a bug?

Also sometimes my method is shown multiple times in the onClick field of the Property-Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Android Studio update.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem on Android Studio 2.2.

For me it does not change the name of the method but also adds "(MainActivity)" to the attribute. I deleted that part in text editor and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Same here - it looks like a bug or config issue of the Android Studio - it's better to fill in the method name manually to make it work.

Comment: It was solved for me a few days later with an update of Android Studio. Don't know which version it was.